FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES / ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression error
I have the below query where I have added the syntax FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES in the inline view and I am now getting the error ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression error. From what I can tell the column data types are the same. The ORDER BY 4 DESC will execute, but when I add FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES I receive the above error.
Select * from 
( ( 
SELECT item_number,item_DESCRIPTION     
      ,decode(substr(subinventory_code,1,3),'11C','11CCL'
              ,'11O','11OPR'
              ,'18O','18OPR'                  
              ,subinventory_code
             ) subinventory_code
      ,p_inv,
       to_char(round(Cost,2),'FM99990.90') Cost,           
       patient_charges, 
       ,rownum ivt_seqnum                  
       ,  CONSIGNED_FLAG  
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT   
                ESI.item_number,
                replace(replace(ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION,chr(10)),chr(13))              item_DESCRIPTION,
                IOQD.subinventory_code,
                IOQD.inventory_item_id                 p_inv,
                to_char(TC.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.99') Cost,                    
                ESI.attribute3
                patient_charges,                    
                ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG 
                          
FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD,
       egp_system_items ESI,
       
       (SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,                    
                to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
               ,TO_CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC)) rownum1
                      FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                           CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                           CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                     WHERE 1=1
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                  
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                             
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID                         
                       
                        
    ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
    ) 
    WHERE rownum1 = 1  AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL 
    
    UNION ALL 
    
SELECT * FROM (  
SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,    
        SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME  SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
        NVL(to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),LN.UNIT_PRICE) TRANSACTION_COST       
        
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID , decode(substr(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME,1,3),                                                           
                                                  '11C','11CCL'
                                                  ,'11O','11OPR'
                                                  ,'18O','18OPR'                                                                 
                                                 ,SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) 
                ORDER BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) rownumber
    FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
       ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC
         ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
        ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
        ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM       

     WHERE 
      SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY         
      AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID 
      AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND UOM.UOM_CODE(+) = LN.UOM_CODE
      AND INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num  )
     WHERE rownumber = 1 ORDER BY 4 DESC FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES  
      )   TC
      
      WHERE  1 = 1
       AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
       AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
        AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.subinventory_code
          AND TC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = IOQD.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                   
     ) )   ) results     
      
      


to_char in 4th column of first select statement in UNION ALL results in data type mismatch with 4th column of second select statement in the UNON ALL.

@keithwalsh Thank you, I'm curious how it worked ok before I added FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES as I thought the UNION still would have forced the data types to be same, so it seems like I should have had this error even before making this change.

ORDER BY 4 DESC FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES refers to the fourth column and Oracle can't implicitly convert data types for ordering.

Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm
